# Uncaught TypeError javascript/jQuery with Array being undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, push, cart

Pastebin of the code because it's not formatted correctly when I post it here
https://pastebin.com/D9exuzK7

I noticed there are more threads but I tried reading those suggestions and since I'm fairly new to jQuery / Javascript I am having trouble seeing where my actual error is. I have tried switching my array to

```
var cart = new Array();
```

and other suggestions but I still seem to be getting this error when I click my button to add an item to the cart.

```
$(".add-to-cart").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = $(this).attr("data-name");
    var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));

    addItemToCart("Prank", 350, 1);
    displayCart();
});

var cart = [];

var items = function(name,price,count) {
    this.name = name
    this.price = price
    this.count = count
}

function addItemToCart(name, price, count) {
    for (var i in cart) {
        if (cart[i].name === name) {
            cart[i].count += count;
            return;
        }
    }

    var item = new items(name, price, count);
    cart.push(item);
    saveCart();
}
```

Comment: Your error must be coming from somewhere else. Your code posted here seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/sqoopuae/

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: Please show us your displayCart() function and error you are getting.

Comment: The exact errror is   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of null
    at addItemToCart (js.js:41)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (js.js:9)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.js:5206)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.js:5014)

Comment: display cart:  function displayCart() {
  var cartArray = listCart();
  var output = "";
  for (var i in cartArray) {
   output += "<li>" + cartArray[i].name + " " + cartArray[i].count + "</li>"
  }
  $("#show-cart").html(output);
 }